# Is the oasis object recognition and training framework available for download

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the oasis object recognition and training framework available for download and are there any other alternate frameworks for object learning that anyone would suggest?
Thanks,
-Scott

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43540/is-the-oasis-object-recognition-and-training-framework-available-for-download/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2012-09-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i've not heard about oasis. for object training and recognition, i think the following two are amazing:

one is tod(texture object detection): http://ros.org/wiki/tod_core

the other is MOPED(Object Recognition and Pose Estimation for Manipulation): http://personalrobotics.ri.cmu.edu/projects/moped

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0